# dynamic positioning of html element

Tags: jquery, css, html

below-mentioned is a sample code wherein I am trying to dynamically create a tabbed experience.

html :

```
<ul id="menu">
    <div class="dialog">
        <li>
            <input type="button" value="Tab 1"></input>
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </li></div>
<div class="dialog">
        <li>
            <input type="button" value="Tab 2 - hello world hello world"></input>
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

css :

```
.close {
  color: #777;
  font: 14px/100% arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

.close:after {
  content: '✖';
}

.dialog {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 205px;
}

ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#menu li input {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li input:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

JQ :

```
function newTab(){
  $('#tab2').val("hello world hello world hello world");
}
```

link : [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwbapK)

problem : clearly, width of dialog class button is hardcoded, but I need to adjust position of close class anchor ('X' in my example), dynamically.

Comment: Your structure is incorrect...you can't have a div inside a `ul` like that.

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D, pls refer above mentioned codepen link, it is working, structure might be wrng, but req is such that I might need to show/hide divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of the dialogue box has to be flexible for the close box to still remain within or adjust as the box grows.

**Solution:**  Change **width** to **min-width** for **.dialog**

```js
function newTab(){
  $('#tab2').val("hello world hello world hello world");
}
```

```css
.close {
  color: #777;
  font: 14px/100% arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  top: 5px;
}

.close:after {
  content: '✖';
}

.dialog {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 205px;
}

ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#menu li input {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li input:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
    <div class="dialog">
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="tab1" value="Tab 1"></input>
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </li></div>
<div class="dialog">
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="tab2" value="Tab 2"></input>
            <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="newTab()" value="Click"></input>
```

Comment: even just removing min-width attribute got it working.
Thanks, marking the answer, accepted.

Comment: That's even better. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your post is rather misleading. When i saw "tabbed experience" i am thinking along lines of tabs.
Back to your question. Your close button is defined to be 5px from the right of your dialog div.
So you really need to be changing the width of your dialogue div.

Eg. if your div is 200px by default.
when you click on the button, you should

get the width (WidthBeforeChange) of the button before text replacement
get the width (WidthAfterChange) of the button after text replacement
add the difference of WidthAfterChange-WidthBeforeChange to the width of your dialog div.

----- The above is a JS solution, here is a css solution ---

```
.dialog {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 205px;  /*change it from a fixed width to a min width*/
}

/** add this to your code **/
.dialog input[type="button"]{
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```